# Invalid Character in a SQL request with Vim

Tags: oracle, vim, encoding

I'm facing a weird issue since yesterday. I'm coding a PHP webservice with request a Oracle DB.

I write a request in vim, say:

```
 SELECT
      RBK_ISBREF AS ISBREF,
       RBK_KEY AS BL_KEY,
       RBK_USERID AS USER_ID,
FROM RULBLACKLIST
WHERE
     RBK_KEY = 'identiteClient'
     AND RBK_VALUE = 'foo'
```

It returns `ORA-00911 Invalid Character`. 
The weird part is,  my request is OK in SQL developper (and returns values) and if i change my IDE from Vim to whatever it returns the correct values…

Is is a format/encoding missconfiguration in Vim ?

In my .vimrc i got these:

```
set fileformat=unix
set fileformats=unix,dos

" Indentation
"-----------------------
"-----------------------
set autoindent
set smartindent
set backspace=indent,eol,start

" Convert tabs to spaces
set  tabstop =4
set  shiftwidth =4
set  softtabstop =4
set  expandtab
```

Any tips?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but since you're asking for tips: remove spaces around `=` in `set` commands.  Spaces around `=` are ok only in `let`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file's encoding; Vim might write in a format that the Oracle tool doesn't understand.

```
:setlocal fileencoding? bomb? fileformat?
```

Especially a *byte order mark* might be the culprit. Alternatively, you can also do a *binary* compare of otherwise identical good and bad files.

Comment: Encoding is `utf-8 [unix]`, i tried the `setlocal no-bomb`  but i still get that error…